# How do I extract vector graphics from a pdf document?

Tags: pdf

I want to make a tool that extracts vector graphics from a pdf file with the help of a human. e.g. A person opens the pdf document using the tool and then selects the objects that he wants to save as a vector drawing. Are there any tools out there already doing this or any libraries that can be used to write my own tool. Language of the library can be(in decreasing preference) c#, VB.net, python or c/c++.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a tedious way, but if you print it using the XPS Document Writer, the vector graphics should be there in WPF XAML that you can use. The output document is just a zip archive with the different document elements